# Select element broken when floated

Tags: html, css

The currency area (`#currencySelect`) on the top left stops dropping down when it's floated left, as it is now. - http://trendy-menswear.myshopify.com/

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="currencySelect" />
<header id="top" class="clearfix" />
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#currencySelect {
    float: left;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

When I remove the float the dropdown functions again.

Any pointers on how to position it where it is currently but have it function?

Comment: Please try to isolate the problem and post the relevant code here in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply the `float:left;` it enters under the header. So you can't click it.

Use `position: absolute;z-index: 101;` rather than `float:left;`.

Comment: Fantastic, just what I was looking for. Thanks Thanasis.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution would be to add:

```
#currencySelect {
    position:relative;
    z-index:101
}
```

Currently the `#top` <header>, having a `z-index: 100`, is positioned over the `#currencySelect` <div> as the latter is removed from the normal layout flow due to floating.

Answer (score 0):

the z-index of `header#top` is 100, covering this , give it an even higher z-index.

Comment: All in all this answer is a complete duplicate of Leon's answer which was posted before.